# convert object values to object keys in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the next object:

```
const obj1 = {
  a: 'x',
  b: 'y',
  c: 'z',
}
```

I want obtain type like this, automatically:

```
type Type = {
  x: number,
  y: number,
  z: number,
}
```

I have thought something like:

```
type Type = {[key in Object.values(obj1)]: number}
```

But obviously this not working.

**SOLUTION**

With help of @jcalz I managed to do it generic:

```
type ObjectKeysFromValues<
  O extends { [key: string | number]: string | number},
  V = string,
> = Record<O[keyof O], V>
```

And this can be used like this:

```
const obj2: ObjectKeysFromValues<typeof obj1> = {
  x: '1',
  y: '1',
  z: '1',
}
```

or

```
const obj2: ObjectKeysFromValues<typeof obj1, number> = {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  z: 1,
}
```

Maybe I should better the namming

Comment: Did you try key of (not key in)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJqB6m) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Note that your `obj1` as defined is of type `{a: string, b: string, c: string}` so there's no way to figure out `"x"`,`"y"`, or `"z"` from that; you need to change your definition of `obj1` so that the compiler keeps track of string literal values (hence the `as const`).  Also note that your example has syntax errors; please [edit] the question to add commas in the appropriate places.

Comment: That was what i was looking for, If you write the solution I will can check it

Answer (score 2):

first you should add "as const" after your obj1 definition.

```
const obj1 = {
  a: "x",
  b: "y",
  c: "z",
} as const;
```

now you have 2 options to define your type.

1.using index signatures

```
type Type = {
    [P in typeof obj1[keyof typeof obj1]]: number
}
```

2.using "Record" that is a built-in utility type like this:

```
type Type = Record<typeof obj1[keyof typeof obj1], number>
```